# Why downloading a file throws multiple disposition error ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a webgrid and I have put a download button inside it to download a file from the grid.

But it throws an error: **localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION**

```
 [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult DownloadStories()
       {

           string filename = "saddam.png";
           string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + filename; //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/UploadedFiles/" + filename;
           byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
           string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

           var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
           {
               FileName = filename,
               Inline = true,
           };

          // Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
           Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

           return File(filedata, contentType, cd.FileName);


       }
```

View:

```
 WebGrid wgImages = new WebGrid(listData, rowsPerPage: 20);
        @wgImages.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive", 
        columns: wgImages.Columns(
                                  wgImages.Column
                                  (columnName: "Image", header:"Image"),
                                  wgImages.Column
                                  (columnName:"Story", header: "Story"),
                                  wgImages.Column
                                  (columnName:"Image", header:"Download", format: (testItem)=> Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadStories", "Stories")

                                 ))
        );
    }
```

I have tried the code which I have commented now and that doesn't work too.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.Byte[],System.String,System.String%29): "The *fileDownloadName* parameter is used to generate the content-disposition header." - so *you don't have to* do that yourself.

Comment: Try remove `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");` since this may causing duplicated headers. `cd.FileName` itself already declares `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition` which required to send file in client's browser.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto ok but now it only opens the file in viewer not downloading

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: ok but now it opens the file instead of downloading

Comment: Ultimately, if the `content-disposition` is coming through as you want it to, the decision on *what behaviour to perform at the client end* is up to the browser.

Comment: `content-disposition` usually ends up in client's browser decision for view or download, depending on selected action chosen for corresponding content type (by default it may set to "always ask", i.e. asking for view in browser or save it to hard drive).

Comment: is that a image file you try to downloading ??

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple HTML & JAVASCRIPT TO download the file by making an ajax call

**1. Call this funcation by ajax post**

```
[HttpPost]
       public JsonResult DownloadStories(String someParamsIfany)
       {
               //do your thing 

        return Json(file,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
       }
```

**2. create an Img file with the data & download it on Html Side**

```
 $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",          
            url: '/Home/DownloadStories',   
            data: {someParamsIfany :someParamsIfany},  
            success: function (result) {  
                DownLoadTheFile(result);
            }
      });
```

**3 now function DownLoadTheFile**

```
function DownLoadTheFile(file){
     var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = file.filepath ;
    a.download =  file.filename;
    a.click();
}
```